# Mathematica FullSimplify[Sqrt[5+2 Sqrt[6]]] yields Sqrt[2]+Sqrt[3] but FullSimplify[-Sqrt[5+2 Sqrt[6]]] is not simplified, why?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I was playing with the (beautiful) polynomial `x^4 - 10x^2 + 1`.
Look what happens:

```
 In[46]:= f[x_] := x^4 - 10x^2 + 1
          a = Sqrt[2];
          b = Sqrt[3];
          Simplify[f[ a + b]]
          Simplify[f[ a - b]]
          Simplify[f[-a + b]]
          Simplify[f[-a - b]]
 Out[49]= 0
 Out[50]= 0
 Out[51]= 0
 Out[52]= 0

 In[53]:= Solve[f[x] == 0, x]
 Out[53]= {{x->-Sqrt[5-2 Sqrt[6]]},{x->Sqrt[5-2 Sqrt[6]]},{x->-Sqrt[5+2 Sqrt[6]]},{x->Sqrt[5+2 Sqrt[6]]}}
 In[54]:= Simplify[Solve[f[x] == 0, x]]
 Out[54]= {{x->-Sqrt[5-2 Sqrt[6]]},{x->Sqrt[5-2 Sqrt[6]]},{x->-Sqrt[5+2 Sqrt[6]]},{x->Sqrt[5+2 Sqrt[6]]}}
 In[55]:= FullSimplify[Solve[f[x] == 0, x]]
 Out[55]= {{x->Sqrt[2]-Sqrt[3]},{x->Sqrt[5-2 Sqrt[6]]},{x->-Sqrt[5+2 Sqrt[6]]},{x->Sqrt[2]+Sqrt[3]}}
```

`Sqrt[5-2 Sqrt[6]]` is equal to `Sqrt[3]-Sqrt[2]`.
However, Mathematica's `FullSimplify` does not simplify `Sqrt[5-2 Sqrt[6]]`.

**Question: Should I use other more specialized functions to algebraically solve the equation? If so, which one?**

Comment: LeafCount@Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[6]] gives 13, and LeafCount[Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[2]] gives also 13. Try to use the ComplexityFunction for Simplify to customize what is considered simpler for you. I think Mathematica uses LeafCount by default.

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi From the _GuideBook for Symbolics_: "The meaning of `Automatic` in the `ComplexityFunction` option setting is basically to minimize the `LeafCount`.  Some exceptions are made for numbers."  For example, `Simplify[Exp[Log[12] + 13 (Sqrt[2] + 1)^2 Log[6] - 2*13 Sqrt[2] Log[6]]]` isn't an `Integer`, although `Integer`s have `LeafCount` `1`.

Comment: No need to include the answer in the question ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed, `Solve` doesn't simplify all roots to the max:

[image]

A `FullSimplify` postprocessing step simplifies two roots and leaves two others untouched:

[image]

Same initially happens with `Roots`:

[image]

Strange enough, now `FullSimplify` simplifies all roots:

[image]

The reason for this is, I assume, that for the default `ComplexityFunction` some of the solutions written above in nested radicals are in a sense simpler than the others.

BTW `FunctionExpand` knows how  to deal with those radicals:

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 for `FunctionExpand` - I wouldn't have thought to use it on `Sqrt` or `Power` functions of integers...

Comment: @Sjoerd Thanks, very educating. Mathematica is almost like mathematics itself. Once you think you have mastered it, new mountains to climb appear at the horizon.

Comment: @Sjoerd In v.7 FullSimplify[Solve[x^4 - 10 x^2 + 1 == 0, x]] yields {{x -> Sqrt[2] - Sqrt[3]}, {x -> -Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3]}, {x -> -Sqrt[ 5 + 2 Sqrt[6]]}, {x -> Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3]}}  while in v.8 two radicals remain not FullSimplified. Strange enough.    Congratulations for Mathematica golden badge !

Comment: +1 (voted already some time ago), and congrats with the Mathematica Gold badge!

Comment: @Leonid Thanks! Yoda told me before I was aware of it. I think I should quit now. All goals in life achieved...  ;-)

Comment: @Sjoerd You can't - SO Mathematica tag needs you more than ever! :). Particularly given the prospect of the new SE Mathematica proposal (we just entered the commitment phase, by the way - since I did not see you commited I assume you don't yet know about that).

Comment: With the commotion over Heike's I missed your graduation.  My belated congratulations on the Gold Mathematica Badge.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard We're a small party right now the four of us. Hope that others will join soon. Alas, we have to build up rep again if the proposal succeeds.

Comment: If questions are migrated to the new site what happens to Reputation points?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No idea. Will questions be moved? Perhaps yoda knows?

Comment: Apparently if they are [all answers are lost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6378/do-migrated-questions-migrate-reputation-and-badges).  At least circa 2009.  I thought I had seen question migrated *with* answers though, so maybe it has changed?

Comment: @yoda Any clue wrt the above 4 comments?

Answer (score 7):

```
FullSimplify[ Solve[x^4-10x^2+1==0,x]
, 
  ComplexityFunction -> 
   (StringLength[ToString[
      InputForm[#1]]] & )]
```

gives

```
{{x -> Sqrt[2] - Sqrt[3]}, {x -> -Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3]}, {x -> -Sqrt[2] -
 Sqrt[3]}, {x -> Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3]}}
```

Comment: Nice it obviously works but i don't buy that you should add ComplexityFunction -> 
   (StringLength[ToString[
      InputForm[#1]]] & )] every time you want a correct answer.